# Getting 'Unable to find Object' Error in Katalon studio

Tags: katalon-studio

Getting 'Unable to find Object' error for the stored object in object repository of Katalon studio. However, when the selector for that element is searched in 'inspect element', it shows the correct element.

```
WebUI.verifyElementPresent(findTestObject('Object Repository/Dimensions_DataSelector/Template Editor Object/Page_Blank Template (On Demand)/span_TotalUS'), 10, FailureHandling.CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE)
```

Comment: You need to show the relevant part of HTML and how is `'Object Repository/Dimensions_DataSelector/Template Editor Object/Page_Blank Template (On Demand)/span_TotalUS'` object defined in Object Repository (e.g. css, xpath, id...).